# Information on a photo of a German soldier boy who served during the 2nd world war

Tags: germany, world-war-2, photo-identification, photo, north-rhine-westphalia

[image]

I have a photo of a German youth soldier who was captured by American forces somewhere in the Ruhr area in March 1945.

Can you give me some details as to who the young German soldier boy is?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  A photograph can be included in your question by using the edit button beneath it to access the picture icon/button and browse to it on your file system.  However, I am going to take a guess that the boy soldier is probably 15 years or younger in 1945 which would mean that born in or after 1930 he would be no more than 84 years old, if still alive.  Consequently, I would like to make you aware of a current discussion we are having at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/how-much-detail-should-be-included-in-questions-about-ww1-and-ww2-service-member

Comment: The result of the discussion mentioned in my previous comment is that we would be keen to have you post your photograph along with anything you know about when and where it was taken.  We will just need to be a little careful about making an identification vs helping you to further your own research because our privacy policy prevents us publishing the name, date of birth, etc for anyone who is living or potentially living.

Comment: @Historian45 Could you send me the UNCROPPED photo so I can see all of the insignia on his uniform. Use my username at g mail or post the uncropped one. If you have any other information such as who was else is in photo would be of help.